# Username changed to Guid

Tags: bug

Yesterday, after I posted a question, and replying in the comments, my username suddenly changed inti a Guid, while it was first `nl-x`. Now it suddenly is `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae`.

Does anyone have any idea if I need to do something to remedy this?

## edit:

I was able to change back my name in `profile` => `display name`. Still would like to know what could have caused this.

Answer (score 3):

This happens occasionally, due to some part of user account maintenance failing for some reason. The reference is [Why is my profile messed up on a single site and how can I revert it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279526/why-is-my-profile-messed-up-on-a-single-site-and-how-can-i-revert-it) 
and posts linked to it, such as [Profile name and icon are broken, but only on Coffee.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290915/profile-name-and-icon-are-broken-but-only-on-coffee-se).